# JSON.parse error, won't parse something I just JSON.stringify'd

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

So I have this really large object that I use to control things in a nodejs app. Occasionally I store this object in a database [mysql] so if the process crashes or gets restarted and something's been changed, the changes will be saved. Pretty simple.

The object is this: http://snippi.com/s/z5nq0v5

it's defined as global.config.

So to store, I use my save function:

```
    client.query('SELECT data FROM settings WHERE (id = \''+ config.room +'\')',
        function(a, b, c) {
            if (!b[0]) {
                client.query('INSERT INTO settings (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)', [config.room, JSON.stringify(config)],
                    function (a) { if (a) throw a;Log("Saved settings"); }
                );
            } else {
                client.query('UPDATE settings SET data="?" WHERE id="'+config.room+'"',
                    [JSON.stringify(config)],
                function (a) { if (a) throw a;Log("Saved settings"); }
            );
            }
        }
    );
```

and that seems to work. However, when I try to load it after I change something, and it saves,
I get an error. This is the loading code:

```
    client.query('SELECT data FROM settings WHERE (id = \''+ config.room +'\')',
        function(a, b, c) {
            console.log(b.length);
            if (a) return console.log(a);
            if (!b[0]) return db.save("settings");
            console.log(b[0].data);
            config = JSON.parse(b[0].data);
            Log("Loaded Settings");
        }
    );
```

As you can see, all I'm really doing is calling JSON.parse() of the object I just stringified earlier. Yet I'm getting an error. The error is

```
undefined:1
3Th0seB310W","ui
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

but there isn't a ' in the area where it's talking about. If you refer to the object up there.

These are the results form console.log(b[0].data): http://snippi.com/s/tknlgyo

Any help would be appreciated, and I'll add more info if it's needed.
Note: the auth code has obviously been changed, but it's just a hex value like the uid below it, just longer.

Comment: Can you show the save code as well? Also, can you show us precisely what is logged when you run `console.log(b[0].data])`?

Comment: Updated. It appears to not be escaping some of the single quotes. I thought stringify did that for you?

Comment: Not sure why your string isn't parsing okay. After escaping all the single quotes, it does parse for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/xHWM4/1/

Comment: @RayToal I just escaped all of them in the config, so the initial save should stringify those, just in case, but it's still coming out unescaped when I try to parse. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for posting the result of console.log.  Are those outer single quotes part of the console.log output?  Assuming yes and editing my answer.

Comment: I could `JSON.parse(data)` without problems after re-escaping the single quotes and removing the outer ones: http://pastebin.com/Kh7Ws7WK. Are you sure `b[0].data` is a string?

Comment: It should be. I JSON.stringify'd the object. Doesn't that turn it into a string?

Comment: @DaltonGore yes, but it went in and out of the DB meanwhile, that's at least three points where it could be mangled.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi I just checked on another object, and it's not being returned with quotes. So I have no idea what's going on anymore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The output of console.log has single quotes.  That means the string you are trying to parse has them.  Strip them before parsing.

For example, here is a a session using node:

```
> console.log("abc")
abc
```

The snippet you posted showed the single quotes.  node did not put them there, so they must have gotten in your data somehow earlier.  Make sure to suppress those when you generate and store your string.

Comment: I have updated my original config array to this: http://snippi.com/s/g7w0c09 and am still getting the exact same thing.

Comment: The problem is not with the original object.  The single quotes are not a problem inside a JSON string.  The problem was that when you did  `console.log(b[0].data)` you got something delimited at the start and end by single quotes.  The question is _why is Node.js logging something with single quotes?_ How did those single quotes get around `b[0].data`?

Comment: From it being stringify'd? I'm not sure either.

Comment: @DaltonGore I bet on the DB adapter you're using. Do other string values saved to the db come back wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: That would be a no. I used the same stringify/parse method on another object in another table, and it comes back without the quotes.

Comment: I'm out of clues. Do `data = b[0].data.replace(/^'|'$/g, '')` as a hack till you figure it out?

Comment: @DaltonGore did Ricardo's suggestion (+1 on that) work?  I'd imagine it would.  But the presence of those outer quotes is something that should be figured out eventually.  There is no way that they could have been put there by the `JSON.stringify` call, because a string wrapped in single quotes is simply [not legal JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: @RayToal I've been looking, and it appears the quotes are added whenever I change something in the object. Which is the whole point of me saving it. Tested the hack, and it appears to be working.